# Is it possible to use the same parameter name for multiple events in Google Analytics?

Tags: events, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

If I use the same parameter name for two different events, google analytics will show in custom dimensions & metrics these parameters like this:

item_name[spend_virtual_currency]

item_name[BreakItem]

So the parameter here is item_name (FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterItemName). While Google seems to recognize that these parameters belong to two different events (spend_virtual_currency and BreakItem), when I click on one of the individual event I see both these parameters as listed, and they have the same values and distribution over time. So I'm not sure if these parameters somehow get grouped together, should I avoid using the same parameter name for different events overall?